# Phonegap Install Ionic Framework

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to install ionic framework with npm for cordova project.
But I'm getting error.
npm log ;

```
28596 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
28597 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
28598 error node v0.12.2
28599 error npm  v2.7.4
28600 error code ECONNRESET
28601 error errno ECONNRESET
28602 error syscall read
28603 error network read ECONNRESET
28603 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
28603 error network and is related to network connectivity.
28603 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
28603 error network
28603 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
28603 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
28604 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7781

Comment: Already answered please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/31124491/1276616

Answer (score 0):

Try installing older version of Node (0.10.38). I was too having the same error with newer version of node.

Answer (score 0):

http://ionicframework.com/docs/concepts/development.html

Improved answer below:

By default, brew installs the latest stable version of node (in this case 0.12.4). Based on the warning messages, ionic is expecting a lower version of node.
I was able to to solve this issue by installing a prior version of node (0.10.38).

```
$ brew remove node
$ rm ~/.node   (might want to rename instead)
$ brew install homebrew/versions/node010 
$ node --version
$ v0.10.38
```

Run `npm install -g ionic`  worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a firewall problem try running this command

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```